# Is there a way to inform directly the server from changes on registration ID for a device?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application that uses FCM to receive messages from a custom server. There are some situations when a new registration ID is generated (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register). I can monitor this change from mobile side (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation).
My problem is that I would like to monitor that new token generation from server side. Does Firebase offer this possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built in to Firebase to signal the generation of a new Instance ID token to server-side code.

If you want a server to respond to a token change, you will have to call that server-side code from your FCM client. Note that all token generation is initiated by the client anyway, so you wouldn't be getting called any sooner or more frequently anyway.